# Sort in codeigniter multilanguage

Tags: php, codeigniter, sorting, multilingual

Does anyone know how to sort a dropdown based on the translations of the items? Here is the code:

```
echo form_open('');
$career = array(
    'arquitect'  => lang('arquitect'),
    'dentists'  =>  lang('dentists'),
    'lawyers'   =>  lang('lawyers'),
    'teachers'   => lang('teachers')
    );
echo form_dropdown('career',$career);
echo form_close();
```

How can I sort the dropdown based on the translation, for example lang('lawyers') in spanish would be 'Abogado' and should be in first position.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lang()` function should give you translated values for each key. In this case all you need to do is to use `asort()` to sort your array by values:

```
echo form_open('');
$career = array(
    'arquitect'  => lang('arquitect'),
    'dentists'  =>  lang('dentists'),
    'lawyers'   =>  lang('lawyers'),
    'teachers'   => lang('teachers')
    );
$career = asort($career); // Sort array by translated values
echo form_dropdown('career',$career);
echo form_close();
```

More about `asort()`: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php

Comment: It didnt work. A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
Filename: helpers/form_helper.php
Line Number: 331

Comment: Hard to say without taking a closer look at the whole code. Try printing your sorted array to see if you have correct data in there and there's something you can loop through: `print_r($career)`